# Troubleshooting "Base table or view not found"

Tags: attributes, database, table, system-config, view

I run into the following when trying to enable Flat Categories in the admin config. I don't know why `mm` is being referenced as a table and do not see it declared as a table in any of our modules.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_db.mm' doesn't exist, query was: UPDATE `mg_core_config_data` SET `scope` = ?, `scope_id` = ?, `path` = ?, `value` = ? WHERE (config_id='102')
```

I also see this when trying to enable quick search when editing attributes.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_db.mm' doesn't exist, query was: UPDATE `mg_catalog_eav_attribute` SET `attribute_id` = ?, `frontend_input_renderer` = ?, `is_global` = ?, `is_visible` = ?, `is_searchable` = ?, `is_filterable` = ?, `is_comparable` = ?, `is_visible_on_front` = ?, `is_html_allowed_on_front` = ?, `is_used_for_price_rules` = ?, `is_filterable_in_search` = ?, `used_in_product_listing` = ?, `used_for_sort_by` = ?, `is_configurable` = ?, `apply_to` = ?, `is_visible_in_advanced_search` = ?, `position` = ?, `is_wysiwyg_enabled` = ?, `is_used_for_promo_rules` = ?, `search_weight` = ?, `is_recipe_attribute` = ?, `is_product_searchable` = ?, `is_recipe_searchable` = ?, `api_attribute_id` = ? WHERE (attribute_id = '147')
```

Comment: The error message shows that the database table `mm` inside the database `magento_db` doesn't exist. The strange this is that when you run the UPDATE query for the table `mg_catalog_eav_attribute` you get an error for `mm` table.

Can you show us the complete query including values? Did you check all of your modules?

Comment: That is the part that I'm having trouble with. I'm not sure how to debug this further by knowing where to trigger the SQL output we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging the Magento SQL queries I recommend the following:

- Edit `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`
- Change the following properties to true (line 106)
- A resulting log file is created at `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`

```
/**
 * Write SQL debug data to file
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_debug               = false;

/**
 * Minimum query duration time to be logged
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $_logQueryTime        = 0.05;

/**
 * Log all queries (ignored minimum query duration time)
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_logAllQueries       = false;

/**
 * Add to log call stack data (backtrace)
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_logCallStack        = false;

/**
 * Path to SQL debug data log
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
```

With that you should be able to see all the queries and debug where your wrong query is coming from.

Make sure you undo the changes after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

That mysql debug will do nothing in this instance.

Sounds like either an upgrade to Enterprise that's gone wrong or an incomplete downgrade.

Go to you database and find core_config_data

Go to triggers and remove ALL triggers.

It relates to the mview module found in Magento enterprise

Comment: I reached out to Enterprise support about this issue. After a week of troubleshooting, they ended up providing a SUPEE SQL patch that rebuilt all Magento triggers. I'm sure this could be extracted, and may have been, directly from Magentos install SQL.